# How to pass and render symbols in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass a symbol into a method and have it

```
def block
  @something = Something.find(1)
  hsh = {:type => :method_to_perform}
  hsh.each { |k, v| nil_test k, v }
end

def nil_test k, v
  @something.try(:k) ? (@k = @something.k.v) : nil
end
```

I'm running into one or maybe two issues, first I think passing the symbol isn't acting as a method on `@something`. How do you pass a symbol and have it act as a method into another block?

Second, I want the key to become the symbol, in others words in the above example I want `@k` to be `@type`, not `@k`. Know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) (or [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send)):

```
@something.try(k) ? instance_variable_set(:@k, @something.send(k).send(v)) : nil
```

You might as well just do

```
instance_variable_set(:@k, @something.try(k).try(v))
```

which is equivalent.

Comment: That partially worked.
If I rewrite the second method as @type = @something.send(k).send(v) it works. I think the try method and the @k assigning are still goofed.

Comment: Have you seen how to name the instance variable as the hash key? For example @k would become @type in if k = :type.

Comment: Whoops, it should also be `try(k)` instead of `try(:k)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Andrew thanks that did solve the try method issue, but the instance variable still isn't being set to the hash's key.

Comment: This is important because the loop should set each instance variable name based on the hash key.

Comment: Oh I see, you want the instance variables name to be dynamically set as well. You can't do `@k` expecting an instance variable with the name of the value of `k`—you'll get an instance variable `@k`. You always need to use methods do do something dynamic like that. (Answer updated.)